# How to delete all lines in text file that is NOT a number greater than a specific value? (Including strings)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

### My Issue:

I am looking into a text file and i need to delete all the lines, or use `string.empty` that does not meet the requirement. For example,

The requirement is 50000. There are words/text in the file and also numbers that are smaller than the requirement. How can i delete all line in a text file that do not meet the requirement? I do not want to be specific with the other values in the text file as they can differ.

### My Research:

I have searched and found to delete specific values then rewrite them onto a new file which i am trying to do. I have found different ways that dont meet my needs. I am using what i have found below but am missing something to make it complete

### My Effort:

```
            DialogResult openFile = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (openFile == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                string content = File.ReadAllText(file);
                SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
                sfd.Filter = "Text File|*.txt";
                sfd.FileName = "New Text Doucment";
                sfd.Title = "Save As Text File";
                if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string path = sfd.FileName;
                    StreamWriter bw = new StreamWriter(File.Create(path));
                    bw.WriteLine(content);
                    bw.Close();
                    File.WriteAllLines(path, File.ReadAllLines(path).Select(x => string.Format("{0},", x)));
                    string newContent = File.ReadAllText(path);
                    newContent = newContent.Remove(newContent.LastIndexOf(","));
                    File.WriteAllText(path, newContent);
                    string secondContent = File.ReadAllText(path);
                    int number = int.Parse(File.ReadAllText(path));
                    if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
                    {
                        secondContent = secondContent.Replace("BRUSH(1,0)", string.Empty);
                        secondContent = secondContent.Replace("REGION 1,", string.Empty);
                        secondContent = secondContent.Remove(secondContent.LastIndexOf(","));
                        File.WriteAllText(path, secondContent);
                        if (secondContent.Contains())
                        {
                            number = 0;
                            secondContent = secondContent.Replace(number.ToString(), string.Empty);
                            File.WriteAllText(path, secondContent);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (checkBox2.Checked == true)
                    {
                        secondContent = secondContent.Replace("BRUSH(1,0),", ")),");
                        secondContent = secondContent.Replace("REGION 1,", string.Empty);                          
                        secondContent = secondContent.Remove(secondContent.LastIndexOf(","));
                        File.WriteAllText(path, secondContent);
                    }
                    //Just trying
                    foreach (char c in secondContent)
                    {
                        if (secondContent.All(char.IsDigit))
                        {
                            char = string.Empty;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

What i am doing above:

- Grabbing an existing file,
- adding the contents to a new file,
- add a comma at the end of each line,
- removing the last comma at the end of the file.
- removing a line that contains brush or region

Now here are examples of the file:

```
TYPE_CODE char(2),
DESCRIPT0 char(25),
TYPE_COD0 char(3),
DESCRIPT1 char(36),
DATA,
BRUSH(1,0),
REGION(1,0),
13502,
319621.99946835 110837.002493295,
319640.501385461 110850.59860145,
319695.199120806 110879.700271183,
319728.303041127 110879.300385649,
319752.898058391 110876.501186912,
319767.401120868 110872.702274339,
```

**The numbers at the bottom of that example is what the entire document should look like**

Comment: learn to use the string.Join function and you won't have to append and or remove `comma's` from the end.. also I would create a class that mimics the structure of your file, then from there have a List<T> of that class to make it easier to add and or remove from the list based on your specific conditions.. but that's just how I would approach it..

Comment: What would i be joining together?

Comment: What do you mean by "The requirement is 50000"? Do you mean you cannot have more than 50000 lines? Do you have other requirements?

Comment: I mean the requirement as an example. Every line must be a number 50000 or greater else it should be deleted. Just an example

Comment: @MethodMan string.Join would be a little messy here because OP is not making one giant file line. So they would need to join, not just on a comma, but  on a comma + new line.

Comment: You might use `IEnumerable<string>` to store lines, the `File.WriteAllLines()` method to overwrite your file and something like `HashSet<string>` when you need to check certain line against some regex or a string... smth like `if(myHash.Contains(line)) { lines.Remove(line);` }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address just the issue stated try the following:

```
//Get the lines from the file
List<string> lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("MyFile.txt").ToList();
//Removed the lines which are empty or when split using ' ' contain items other the numbers >= 50000
double d = 0;
lines.RemoveAll(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x) || x.TrimEnd(',').Split(' ').Any(y => !double.TryParse(y, out d) || double.Parse(y) < 50000));
//Write the new file
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("MyFile2.txt", lines.ToArray());
```

To add a comma to the end of each line add the following lines before saving:

```
//Remove any existing ',' and add our own
lines = lines.Select(x => x.TrimEnd(',') + ",").ToList();
//Remove any trailing ',' from the last line
lines[lines.Count - 1] = lines[lines.Count - 1].TrimEnd(',');
```

(Edited to handle multiple numbers per line)
(Fixed conversion errors)
(Fixed for existing ',')

Comment: the .ToList wont work on a list of strings? At least what vs tells me. Also cant convert null from out double

Comment: I expect there is a conversion error as I work in VB.NET.

Comment: Are you importing System.Linq?

Comment: I have fixed the conversion errors. In VB.NET you can get away without the () at the end of parameterless functions, the converter dosn't take that into account.

Comment: lines is set in the very first line when reading in the existing lines from the file.

Comment: Im not sure why this isnt working for me. The file is not containing any of the correct values like it should in the bottom of the question

Comment: It's the existing ',' at the end, causing the TryParse to fail. Updated to handle this.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to make an exception for 2 closing brackets? `))` since the is nullorwhitespace kind of ruins that part

Comment: Try creating a function which accepts the line and determins if to keep it or not and use it in the RemoveAll expression

Answer (score 0):

First, abstraction would be your friend here. Break up your code into different peices to make it a little easier to handle. Plus when you have to change your requirements later, you will have an easy spot to do it.

Second, `File.ReadLines` is also your friend because it will give you a collection of strings, which will let you use LINQ.

Which brings me to your third friend, LINQ, which will let you query the collection of file lines.

```
public void FormatFile(string sourcePath, string targetPath)
{
    IEnumerable<String> originalContent = GetFileLines(sourcePath);
    IEnumerable<String> formatedContent = ProcessFileLines(originalContent);
    OutputResults(targetPath, formatedContent);
}

public IEnumerable<String> GetFileLines(string path) {
    return File.ReadLines(path);
}

public IEnumerable<string> ProcessFileLines(IEnumerable<string> fileLines)
{        
    // In this method you can process the logic that applies to the whole
    // set of file lines (e.g. lineCount, removing empyLines, etc)
    return processedLines.Select(l => ProcessLine(l)
                         .Where(l => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(l))
                         .GetRange(0, MAX_LINE_COUNT);
}


public string ProcessLine(string fileLine)
{
    // In this method just focus on logic applied to each specific line.
    string s = fileLine.Substring(0, 5);

    if (s.Equals("BRUSH", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        return string.Empty;

    return fileLine;
}


public void OutputResults(string targetPath, IEnumerable<string> fileLines)
{
        string outputText = fileLines.Join($",{Environment.NewLine}");
        File.WriteAllText(targetPath, outputText);
}
```

So basically you can just call `FormatFile(@"C:\mySource", @"C:\myTarget");` and you will be good to go.